# What is the best way to synchronise a table in an SQL database with the results of a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I frequently find myself in a situation where I would like to update a database table with the results of some complicated query.

Typically we have a load of data spread across many tables, all nicely normalized so that nothing is duplicated.  But the results of the complicated query are very frequently needed, so we save the results into a separate (denormalized) table (which I will call `results`).  This gives us fast access to the data in `results`, with the tradeoff that it is always slightly out of date, and we have to periodically synchronise.

My question is: what is the best way to update our denormalized `results` table?

I have tried the following approaches already, but both have their own problems.

**Approach 1**

Delete everything from results then insert everything from the long query.

```
DELETE FROM results;
INSERT INTO results (SELECT ... long complicated query here)
```

Problems with this:

- We temporarily lose access to `results` completely
- The insert step puts a lot of strain on the database, there's lots of disk access writing all the data and updating indexes etc

**Approach 2**

Patch the `results` table in place with separate `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries.

1. Find and delete rows from `results` that are no longer present in the complex query
2. Update rows in `results` which have changed in the complex query
3. Insert new rows into `results` which have appeared in the complex query

This means that access to `results` is not interrupted, but the implementation is a lot more difficult. I need to execute the complex query 3 times and join with `results` in different ways to get the `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` parts.

---

Is there a better approach than the 2 mentioned above?  Ideally something that would patch the `results` table instead of rebuilding from scratch, but without all the complexity of doing separate DELETE, UPDATE and INSERT queries?

Note we are using Postgres, but I'm very interested in suggestions for solving this problem in general.

Comment: Wrap the two statements in a single transaction and commit when everything is ready.

Comment: A materialized view perhaps? (Note that I've never used Postgresql, so that might be a bad idea.)

Comment: Approach 3: Run the query once.  Write the results to a flat file.  Run a match/merge to get three flat files, one for inserts, one for updates, and one for deletes.  Generate the SQL to perform the inserts, updates, and deletes.  Execute the SQL in batches of 1000 changes per commit.

Comment: This is similar to your Approach 1, but with some added techniques to minimize disruption:

Create a new, temporary table and populate it with the results of your complicated query.
Once the temporary table is populated, rename the current table (e.g. to "old_results"), rename the temporary table to "results", and then drop the "old_results" table. This switch should happen very quickly, minimizing downtime. However, there may still be some brief moment when the "results" table is not accessible.

Comment: Since youre exploring other ways to do this, in snowflake they have DYNAMIC table types which are sort of like materialized views except you can better control the schedule and don't have to manage or schedule a task

Comment: @FrankHeikens with your suggestions of putting the DELETE and INSERT into a transaction, correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't that mean that while the transaction is being processed, the results table is essentially locked? So don't we have the same problem where we temporarily lose access to it (but instead of queries failing they get queued until the transaction completes?) I worry that backing up queries while the transaction completes might be even more harmful.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions above.  Some really interesting ideas.  I will definitely research materialized views and try to find out if there are any hidden dangers to that approach.  The idea of populating updated data into a new 'staging' table then renaming also sounds good.  I've heard there can be some problem with locking when renaming tables, so I might try another approach where we simply save a table 'version number' in the application, and query the newest results table, IE when `results_24` is created, start using that instead of `results_23` (and periodically drop old ones)

Comment: No, the DELETE won't lock the table for reads, check the manual. Unless you have other processes that also try to delete (or update) these rows.

Comment: The suggestion by @jarlh is precisely what you want. See [Materalized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the downside of my first comment. This an improvement.

Use the same table but with a new batch_id column. And using a view to bring the latest data. You can keep the table name, or use a new name and create the view as results so no changes impact the business.

```
-- Assuming your results table now has a batch_id column
CREATE TABLE results (id INT, c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, batch_id INT);

-- Insert new batch of data with a new batch ID
INSERT INTO results (id, c1, c2, c3, batch_id)
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, :new_batch_id
FROM (/* your complicated query here */);

-- Create or replace the view that points to the latest batch
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW latest_results AS
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3
FROM results
WHERE batch_id = (SELECT MAX(batch_id) FROM results);

-- Then, to clean up old batches of data (if necessary):
DELETE FROM results WHERE batch_id < (SELECT MAX(batch_id) FROM results);
```